# Flower cannot ping celery worker on ECR AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-ecr, flower

Here is the problem I am facing recently :

I have some python scripts that do some data analysis.

The code is deployed in a celery worker which uses a beat and Redis as a broker. I am also using Flower to monitor the tasks.

The Redis instance I am using is a Redis from AWS..

The 3 services use a docker image pushed to an ECR on AWS.

The problem I am having is that when I am trying to ping the worker instance from the flower instance is it not reaching the worker. How can I make the flower communicate with the worker?

When I am running this as docker containers on my local machine everything works without any issue.

Here is how my containers  are defined in the task definition for AWS:

```
{
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "inferenceAccelerators": [],
    "containerDefinitions": [{
      "command": [
        "celery",
        "-A",
        "celery_factory:celery",
        "beat",
        "-S",
        "redbeat.RedBeatScheduler",
        "--loglevel=info"
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "image": "spiny-pi-cards-aws:00000",
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "spiny-pi-cards-logs",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "celery-beat"
        }
      },
      "name": "celery-beat",
      "memory": 256
    },
        {
            "command": [
                "celery",
                "-A",
                "celery_factory:celery",
                "worker",
                "--loglevel=info",
                "-E"
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "spiny-pi-cards-aws:00000",
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "spiny-pi-cards-logs",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "celery-worker"
                }
            },
            "name": "celery-worker",
            "memory": 256
        },
        {
            "command": [
                "./start_flower"
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "FLOWER_PORT",
                    "value": "5556"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "spiny-pi-cards-aws:00000",
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "spiny-pi-cards-logs",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "celery-flower"
                }
            },
            "name": "flower",
            "memory": 256,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 5556,
                    "hostPort": 5556
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "volumes": [],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "memory": "1024",
    "cpu": "256",
    "executionRoleArn": "somesecret_stu",
    "family": "spiny_pi_cards-task-definition",
    "taskRoleArn": "",
    "placementConstraints": []
}
```

And here is how I am running the ping :
This is the content of my `./start_flower.sh`

```
until timeout 10s celery -A celery_factory:celery inspect -d celery@ip.us-east-2.compute.internal ping; do
    >&2 echo "Celery workers not available"
done

echo 'Starting flower'
celery -A celery_factory:celery flower --loglevel=info -E
```

When run inside the flower container, it's not reaching the worker...

It keeps returning worker not avialable...

Comment: can I ask why are you trying to reach the worker from the flower container?

Comment: to test if it is alive in order to run the task...

Comment: from flower? I'm asking because flower connects your broker, not the worker itself

Comment: yeah, ... it's just a sanity check. I don't want flower to start before the worker... if it started before, it cannot pick the task..